# How to convert scatterplot to a heat map

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on a project for my final year design.

I have a data-set i have managed to collect that i would like to plot as a heat map over an image.

What i have managed to do so far is shown by [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiYQ3.png) image.
The code i used to make this image is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

# Generate fake data
x = dd['B']
y = dd['C']

# Calculate the point density
xy = np.vstack([x,y])
z = gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)

# fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=1)
# plt.show()
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(cap)
# plt.scatter(dd['B'],dd['C'],c=dd['A'].apply(lambda x: color(x)),s=2, alpha=0.1)
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap='Reds', s=1, alpha=0.1)
```

so my question is how can make a plot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH5HZ.jpg) for the data-set(just an x and y point ) that i have.

Thank you.

Comment: You could try seaborn's 2D `sns.kdeplot(x=x, y=y, palette='Reds', ...)`

Comment: Hist2d is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following : `plt.imshow(z)`

Comment: Great idea, but the size of the dataset is (60000,2) so it crashes the kernel.

Comment: 'cap' is the background image

Comment: ```TypeError: Invalid shape (15659,) for image data``` for ```plt.imshow(z)```

Comment: `plt.tricontourf(x, y, z, cmap='Reds')`